# Ui like android sliding notification bar for web (html)

Tags: android, html, polymer, material-design, web-component

I am building a desktop app using electron (formerly known as node atom, using html javascript and css).
I want to use (or create if there is no choice) a sliding notification bar, like the one on android OS.

I failed to find existing components for this purpose and not sure how to develop this component myself.

I would like to know if such component or something similiar exists or how I could write one for my own use.

Thanks alot in advance for the help

---

**Update 1**

I was requested, rightfully, to give more info and be more specific.
I will expand on exactly what I need from this status bar, and why I need it and the context in which I need it for. (maybe there are better options that i'm not aware of).

I am writing a desktop app using nodejs electron (so my UI doesn't follow the common browser ui&ux rules).
The template that I have written so far looks like the following:

[image: My initial template]
as you one can see, im trying to make it look as much as "mobile" I can while following google material design (i'm using angular 2, so angular 1 material is not an option, most of the component i'm using are from polymer elements collection)

The heart of my app is about running some algorithms on the server. I want a central place to show which algorithms are currently running and their status (there cant be more then 5 at once usually), so the only idea I could think of that fits material design and is central enough was to use something that looks like the android notification bar. The problem is that I couldn't find any web component that can achieve that. The status bar which i'm talking about looks like the following (The way it looks change a bit when looking at numerious android version, I don't mind exactly like which version it looks like). It should slide down from the top when clicked or dragged down like in an android mobile phone:

[image]

The notifications show whats currently active, I could also use a setting shortcut in it as well (The marked in red areas are the relevant parts). The rest of the options are not relevant.
So that's what I was initially looking for. If someone has a better idea on how to show these running algorithms in a central place, that fits the material design guidelines, I am also open to suggestions :)

Comment: are you trying to achieve a hotspot on the top part of your site? or do you want a button or a keyboard shortcut to slide that notification bar?

Comment: I was thinking about a button which sildes it down or maybe also support of dragging it down, anything close to it will be great

Comment: Anything else you're looking for? how much the same as the notification drawer on Android do you want this to be? Only a component that slides up and down from the top of the screen?

Comment: I would like it to resemble the android one as much as possible. But I only need the notification section (without the android setting section that is on the top). What I want to achieve is to have a place in my app that shows numerious notification and to look as much of an mobile app as possible (I use material design components for the rest of my app). This is a desktop app which im writing using nodejs electron, and not a truely browser app, so it does make sense to me to use something like the sliding notification bar that my user will already be familiar with.

Comment: @user1245668 I know its been a while since you asked this question, but I just wanted to give you a heads up I will be making this just for fun and because I want to use it in the future. I wonder if drag support is a necessity.

Comment: Its still very relevant to me, so It would be very appreciated if you did share it with me :)
Since this is a desktop app, and my user are mainly using laptops with a very shitty mouse, dragging is not very comfortable to them and being able to just click it is a must. But being able to drag as well is cool but not a must (and I could just try to implement it in the future on the component you build, if you will build one)

Comment: Btw, I saw you mainly program with angularjs on your profile, I hope your'e not gonna write this using angularjs 1 since i'm using angularjs 2 which wont work together :( (angular 2 works with everything else, for example polymer, or anything else that uses the web components standarts)

Comment: Any advance on your work 5parc?